# linux: how to permanently and globally change environment variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, bashrc

I want to do the following for every user that logs into my linux box:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.path
```

And I don't know how to do that besides manually adding that line in every ~/.bashrc file.

Also, a cron job of mine runs a program and I want (for that cronjob) the PYTHONPATH set to something specific. will any .bashrc files affect the cronjob's environment? How do I change a cronjob's environment.

Also, I am now curious as to how to change what the PATH variable is on startup. Other programs seem to do this when they're installed, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Environments for shells**

Essentially, anything that runs processes will tend to read a configuration file on starting up, and to affect the environment of that, you need to hit its configuration file.

For user shells, "obvious" places are `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` (I think) and maybe a couple of others I don't remember. Obviously, more and others if you use `zsh`, `csh`, `tcsh` or whatever as a shell.

There are initialization files read by your windowing environment, which may be either KDE or Gnome. The particular window manager you run underneath that may also read a config file. I admit I don't know the names of those files even for my own installation.

Finally, there are usually "master" configuration files for all those environments somewhere in `/etc`. They provide defaults for stuff the users don't.

I think that programs that install themselves conscientiously check the various possibilities. Various Linux distributions may offer some helper scripts for this.

**cron**

This one is a lot easier. For security reasons, `cron` only passes a couple of environment variables to subprocesses, ALWAYS. I think `USER` is one of those, and `MAILTO` another. As far as I know, there's no `PATH` set - this often annoys newbies. **The environment of a cron job is completely different from your shell environment!** Anything you want in the environment, you either pass in on the command line in `crontab`, or you start up a script and let that set up whatever environment it needs.

Comment: actually, I just found a cron example in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327695/django-standalone-run-in-cron

Answer (score 3):

To apply a bashrc change to *all* users, you can modify `/etc/bash.bashrc` (This is for Ubuntu).

Also, as indicated in the answer above, make sure that this file is sourced by `/etc/profile`.